# Kali Linux don't load GUI automatically

Tags: debian, kali-linux, gui, gdm3

I have Gm3 display manager, but recently I installed lxdm display manager. During the installation it prompted me to select the default manager from where I selected lxdm, but upon reboot it booted into cli (not grub rescue) asking login password, so logged in and changed the display manager to gdm3 by `sudo nano /etc/X11/default-display-manager`. I changed it from `/usr/sbin/lxdm` to `usr/sbin/gdm3` but upon reboot it was the same CLI, so I started gdm3 by `sudo systemctl start gdm3.service` and it loaded the GUI. Every time I boot into Kali Linux, I have to do the `systemctl start` step to load the GUI.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this and load the gdm3 GUI automatically?

Comment: Have you read this: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/101265

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to enable it so it auto-starts:

```
sudo systemctl enable gdm3.service
```

Comment: Output :  Synchronizing state of gdm3.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable gdm3
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template
units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.

Comment: This worked for me  ```sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target```